# Which one is faster? Sort data in IQueryable or IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, performance, linq

I have a table with more than 600 millions rows. I have a query (like turnover report query) that select portions of the table (maximum 5% of all data filtered by `RegDate` condition). I want to sort results of this query.

I use indexes on `Id` and `RegDate` columns. Which one is faster? Sort data in `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`?

```
var activites = _turnOverRepository.GetTransactions(account.Id)
                .Where(a => a.RegDate >= fromDate && a.RegDate <= toDate)
                .OrderBy(a => a.RegDate)
                .ThenBy(a => a.RegTime)
                .ToList();
```

OR

```
var activites = _turnOverRepository.GetTransactions(account.Id)
                .Where(a => a.RegDate >= fromDate && a.RegDate <= toDate)
                .ToList();
                .OrderBy(a => a.RegDate)
                .ThenBy(a => a.RegTime)
```

Comment: "I use indexes on Id and RegDate columns." - can You be more specific?

Comment: where is the `5%` filter?

Comment: why you dont try both and measure execution time? Also use sql profiler to check what query is being performed on db and run `explain query`

Comment: @AntonínLejsek data insertion in this table is important too, because if I increase count of indexes then insertion time increases too.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza data filtered by RegDate condition

Comment: But your question say `MAX 5%` how filtering by date guarantee that?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i don't guarantee that, this is the average percent.

Comment: @ArMaN the number of times I have seen under indexing cause problems far outweighs the number of times I have seen over indexing cause problems. it's theoretically possible, but it's cited entirely too often. it's more likely going to cause you tlog bloat, index space issues, and maintenance plan time issues than it is to create any noticeable degradation on speed of inserts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fastest to sort in the database using IQueryable if you have the correct index in place. That's because there's a rule about sorting, where the fastest sort happens on already sorted data. The index will sort the data on insert.

Create a single composite index on (Id, RegDate, RegTime).

Comment: create a single composite index on (Id, RegDate, RegTime) . I doubt that's the best column order

Comment: Doubt? You always put the most selective column first if possible, which would be by id, which also supports GetTransations(), then the next column is in the where clause, and the last one is to support the "order by". I'm not sure where the doubt comes in to play.

Comment: What you mean `the index sort the data on insert` ?? doesnt make much sense, what if you have different index on several fields? You cant sort for each index.

Comment: @MitchWheat are you trying to help answer the question?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza each nonclustered index will maintain a sorted version of the column values for the columns in the index, with a pointer back to the data row. no, it won't technically sort all of the data for each index, unless you create a pseudo secondary clustered index by creating a complete covering index, but it will maintain a sorted list of the values that are determining the sort. this will make the query above not have a sort in the execution plan, just an index range scan with corresponding bookmark lookups.

Comment: @MitchWheat Id can't be the primary key unless something is stated wrong in the original question. it's stated that we're dealing with a single table, and if Id already got us to a single row based on primary key, there would be no sort needed.

Comment: I will have to double check this one, but I have seen sort step in query analyzer even over indexed fields.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza if the sort is needed for a later step in the plan, like for a group by, or if you're dealing with a composite index where you have not filtered down to the column that you're ordering by, or the index is not being range scanned, then yes. in general however, no, that should not be the case. I'll happily work through any examples with you.

Comment: Im already pass my bedtime, If you can prepare a sqlFiddle I will check it tomorrow. Or I will prepare one later. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101836/discussion-between-shriop-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).